# How to save edits/recompile changes made .py files in python?

Tags: python

I apologize in advance for my lack of technical terminology?

Not experienced with Python just trying to make a change to a program that I bought off of a freelancer. There's a couple py files with edits I'm trying to make. I understand you have to do some sort of "recompile" instruction in the terminal to actually save the edits, is that correct?

What's the exact thing I have put into the terminal to actually get this to work?

Comment: Python is an `interpreted` language meaning that the user does not need to compile the code to run it. In this case, python does if for us creating a `.pyc` file. For more information on how python works: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/how.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you simply save the text changes from your editor.  If your IDE uses *.pyc (Python pre-compiled) files, it should note the update (inversion of time stamps), and recompile as needed.  If you don't have pyc files, then there's no update to make - the code is interpreted, so you get the new version at the next invocation.